# How to set proxy on MediaPlayer

Tags: android, proxy, streaming, media-player

In my music stream program, how can I set proxy on `android.media.MediaPlayer` class for stream a link file through the proxy network ? I know about NTCreditional, UsernamePasswordCreditional, Proxy-Authorization Header and etc in `HttpClient`, `URLConnection`. But I can not set proxy on `android.media.MediaPlayer`, how can I do it?

Thanks for your advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately MediaPlayer API doesn't provide a ready-to-use method for proxy setting at the moment.

#### how can I do it?

There is a possible workaround but quite dirty:

1. Download the media contents from the remoteUrl `http://remotehost:80/music`, using whatever technology you familiar with, socket, httpClient and etc. and handle proxy authentication properly here.
2. Open a socket locally (on your mobile device) and write the downloaded data to this socket's OutputStream, what we actually want is republish the downloaded contents to a localUrl `http://localhost:8081/music` running on our mobile device.
3. Feed this localUrl to your MediaPlayer: `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(localURL);` instead of `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(remoteURL);`.

#### Related Materials:

- [Similar SO discussion: Audio stream buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557450/audio-stream-buffering)
- [StreamProxy source code from npr-android-app](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java)

Hope this make sense.

Comment: I will try to program this and will be release it here, for other's use :) Thanks