# Is there any MediaPlayer class to play and cache music on android

Tags: android, media-player

I want to know is there any library or class to play and cache audio files automatically like Picasso for Images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is MediaPlayer Class

[MediaPlayer Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: I know it, but it loads song from internet every time, when you reinitialize it.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) This is ugly but works.
Create local proxy server as in this App. -

http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/

And now get stream Data before mediaplayer is getting.This is where you can implement your own cache logic.

Similar SO questions:

[How to set proxy on MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627278/how-to-set-proxy-on-mediaplayer)

[Audio stream buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557450/audio-stream-buffering)

---

2 )try. http://www.infidian.com/2009/12/27/android-streaming-mediaplayer-tutorial-updated-to-v1-5-cupcake/